# Running drush sql-sync between linux drupal alias as source and windows drupal alias as target throws rsync:chgrp error

Tags: drush

i can see from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/254834/rsync-ubuntu-to-windows-under-cygwin-way-to-avoid-invalid-argument-22-error) post that rsync is trying to set group on the file which may not make sense for windows. The question is, how can i pass rsync options while running the sql-sync command as

```
drush sql-sync @linux_alias @windows_alias
```

I can run the same command between two linux drupal aliases without any problems.

Thanks!

Comment: im not a drush expert. But I imagine you need Cygwin or something similar for Windows. Rsync is not a native Windows command, so spluh it wont work between different OS hosts such as those.

Comment: @tenken Drush on windows installs Cwrsync which is implementation of rsync on windows. I can see the file getting copied in the temp directory, but the problem is, after copying the file to local computer, the Cwrsync tries to update its permissions which fails. And with this the sql-sync also fails.

Comment: Also, if i run the same command with `'no-cache' => FALSE,`, the command runs successfully by using the sql dumped by the earlier command which had failed. Although, this time a new dump is not fetched from the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got it running. Followed instructions at [this blog](http://www.mydrupaljourney.com/articles/2013/03/26/using-drush-sql-sync-overcoming-windows-issues) and i'm able to run it.

Specifically:

> The best way to solve this, is simply to add the following to your
>   alias definition file for your local site:

```
  'target-command-specific' => array (  //commands used when this alias is the target
'sql-sync' => array (
  'create-db' => TRUE,  //create new database(merged databases can be trouble!)
  'mode' => 'rultvz',  // override sql-sync default $mode = '-akz' from rsync.core.inc
),
```

),